# Using jquery / javascript to wrap a series of HTML elements in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, each

I found the following code on stackoverflow in order to wrap a series of elements between two H2 tags with jquery. The code works fine when I employ it on a mock up html page outside of wordpress. But I cannot get it to work within wordpress.

I am able to make other basic scripts work within the WP environment, but this is obviously beyond my limited ability. Here is a link to a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymDrn/ that demonstrates the script.

I have included the script into my WP functions.php like so, it seems to be included correctly as it appears in the head tag after the page has loaded.

**The Scripts Inclusion in WP:**

```
function paraWrapper()  
{  
wp_register_script( 'fpParaWrapper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fpParaWrapper.js', array( 'jquery' ) );  
wp_enqueue_script( 'fpParaWrapper' );  
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'paraWrapper' );
```

**The Script:**

```
jQuery(function fpParaWrapper()
{
    jQuery('h2').each(function(){ 
        var $set = jQuery(this).nextUntil("h2").andSelf();
        $set.wrapAll('<div class="monkey" />'); 
    });
})
```

**The HTML:**

```
<h2>a Heading</h2>
<p>a paragraph</p>
<p>a paragraph</p>

<h2>a Heading</h2>
<p>a paragraph</p>
<p>a paragraph</p>
```

I cannot determine what element of this script it not working with WP and would definitely appreciate some insight from a more knowledgeable developer. I am very comfortable with HTML and CSS but I am still learning the basics of scripting. Let me know if you need more details, I have spent the better part of today trying to work my way through this with no success. Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress you have to replace `$()` with `jQuery()`

Comment: I've changed all occurrences of $() to jQuery() but it is still not working. Thank you for pointing that out to me though.

Comment: Hmm, then I don't know, I'm sorry, maybe someone else can help you futher.

Comment: Alex, I missed one $(), once I changed it... bingo it works!! You were right on! I really appreciate your help, thank you for taking the time to answer!